# Push notification in inactive mode in ibm Mobilefirst

Tags: ios, cordova, apple-push-notifications, ibm-mobilefirst

I am working on native-hybrid bridge Project in IBM Mobile first, where subscription, unsubscription  and push notification action happens in hybrid side.
After receiving in hybrid, they process and send back to native.
It works well with Foreground and background.  But in inactive mode the notification is received and shows notification but the Processing of notifications (like storing, modifying data) are not happening in inactive mode.  Any of native methods including callback method is not called.  Please suggest how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If the application is "inactive" (meaning it is not running, quit), there cannot be "automatic processing" for incoming notifications. This can only happen once the application is launched.

Comment: If native code is not called, then how can i handle it when the notification is clicked in topbar and the app is opened?

Comment: This is done by the framework... you use the same function that is called to handle push when the app is open or in the background.